# Splitting a string in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string based on delimiter in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash)

I have a bunch of files named `test<numbers or letters>.<number>.out` so like `test1.1024.out` or `test2.2.out`. Is there some way I can use a regular expression like `^test.*?..(.*).out$` to parse out the middle number on each file and then be able to access the group?

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in test*.out; do
  number=${f#test*.}
  number=${number%.*}
  echo $f has middle number $number
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r 's/^test[[:alnum:]]*\.([[:digit:]]+)\.out$/\1/'
```

Alternatively (A shorter version of the BASH for loop):

```
awk -F '.' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of Bash this could work too:

```
 test=test1.1024.out
 if [[ $test =~ ^test[A-Za-z0-9]+\.([0-9]+)\.out$ ]]; then
      echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
 fi
```